# Read encrypted buffer from SSL

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to trace an application that written in `C` language and working with `TLS` connection that implemented by `TLS_method()`
the BIO of main `SSL` object is `BIO_s_socket`.
because of integrity of source code I Can't change the BIO type to `BIO_s_mem` or something else. 
I want to read encrypted traffic that received on this `SSL` connection, 
`SSL_read` or `SSL_peek` method only gives me data after decryption.
is there any way to read pure encrypted data received on `SSL's` socket without making problem for `SSL_read` functionality ?

---

I want something like this:

```
char buf[DEFAULT_BUFSIZE];

/* read encrypted data arrived at socket and save it to buf */
SSL_read_encrypted(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));

char decbuf[DEFAULT_BUFSIZE];

size_t n = SSL_read(ssl, decbuf, len);

/* decbuf's data is exactly buf's data after decryption */
```

Comment: You can get the underlying file descriptor with BIO_get_fd and then call recv with MSG_PEEK.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want @JamesKPolk
but I think I should use SSL_get_fd instead of using BIO_get_fd

Comment: Sure, try that.

Comment: I have a problem using SSL_get_fd
when I recv want to recv from this socket I capture network using tcpdump
but the data recv from socket is not the data captured with tcpdump and therefor this is not the exactly encrypted data in network
now what should I do ? :( @JamesKPolk